# What is the type-safe way to have different code block for different types?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to have if condition depended on parameter type.

In following example typescript doesn't recognize that if I pass "cat" as `type` parameter, then `canMeow` should be available in the if condition.

Is there any type-safe way to achieve following?

```js
type Cat = {
    name: string;
    canMeow: boolean;
}

type Dog = {
    name: string;
    canBark: boolean
}

type TypeMap = {
    dog: Dog;
    cat: Cat;
}

type Animal<T> = {
    type: T;
    data: TypeMap[T]
}

function canMakeSound<Type extends keyof TypeMap>(animal: Animal<Type>){
    if(animal.type == "cat"){
        return animal.data.canMeow; // <--- error
    }
    else if(animal.type == "dog"){
        return animal.data.canBark; // <--- error
    }
}

canMakeSound({type: "cat", data: {name: "kitty", canMeow: true}});
```

Comment: You probably want to use [a discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and not a generic function, since the former gives you control-flow narrowing but the latter does not.  It looks [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WGAnJN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no mechanism in TypeScript by which [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters are [narrowed via control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  That is, if `animal` is of generic type `T`, then checking `animal.type` might serve to narrow `animal.type`, but it will *not* narrow or re-constrain `T` itself.  And therefore `animal.data` will stay as `TypeMap[T]` for a `T` the compiler doesn't know.  There are various open issues asking for some improvement here, like [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), but for now it's not part of the language.

So instead giving `animal` a generic type, you should consider a type where the compiler *will* narrow `animal` by checking `animal.type`... namely, a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  Here's how you could generate that type:

```
type Animal = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: {
  type: K;
  data: TypeMap[K]
} }[keyof TypeMap]

/* type Animal = {
    type: "dog";
    data: Dog;
} | {
    type: "cat";
    data: Cat;
} */
```

Here `Animal` is created by immediately [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which makes it the union type shown above.  Either `type` is the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"dog"` and `data` will be `Dog`, or `type` is the literal type `"cat"` and `data` will be `Cat`.  That makes `type` the *discriminant* property of `Animal`, and if you check that property, it will narrow the type of the whole object to just the union member(s) that conform to the check:

```
function canMakeSound(animal: Animal) {
  if (animal.type == "cat") {
    return animal.data.canMeow; // okay
  }
  else if (animal.type == "dog") {
    return animal.data.canBark; // okay
  }
  throw new Error(); // added this due to microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985
}
```

That all works fine, except I added a `throw` line to appease the compiler; it can't tell from those `if`/`else` statements that the `animal.type` check is exhaustive, so it complains that you didn't `return` from the end. This is a known issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985).

And let's test it:

```
console.log(
  canMakeSound({ type: "cat", data: { name: "kitty", canMeow: true } })
); // true

canMakeSound({ type: "dog", data: { name: "kitty", canMeow: true } }); // error!
// ----------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ name: string; canMeow: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Dog'
```

Looks good.  It behaves as expected, and the compiler warns if you pass in a `data` that does not conform to the proper `type`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#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-Z9A8QKKH2hG6NHYxA1ZxyABCQaxgC0bfbHc7Xe7Pd7LYAfFAAH4j0dj0fNvJjADkNrUHs01HoH3YJagAgNYna09SJBwnEQcBIJEoNFwfBE5U4tug0580-QQA)